# Sdcard partitions in Android

Tags: android

I have been trying to understand how Android (> 4.4) organizes its sdcard structure. Based on reading online, I have the following understanding:

- Private section: no permission needed to access this
- Public section: EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is needed

Does the sdcard have any other sections except the two above ?

Answer (score 0):

No there are no other sections. Well, under External Storage you can find two sections: 
1) /storage/emulated/0
2) /storage/emulated/legacy.

To know difference switch to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625104/storage-emulated-legacy-vs-storage-emulated-0-vs-data-data-myapp). Please let me know if you have any other problem in understanding storage!