# Unable to Create Directory

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am trying to write a downloaded file to the storage but I'm getting and error. Here is my code -

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/songs", "name-of-the-file.mp3");
```

Log -

```
03-25 12:40:47.230 10480-10480/com.xxxx.ytm.yyyy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.xxxx.ytm.yyyy, PID: 10480
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /storage/emulated/0/songs

    at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:538)
    at com.antimatter.ytm.youtubemp3.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:84)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

For record, here's the rest of the code -

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
// To work and download on main thread

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downl));
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/songs", "name-of-the-file.mp3");

DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
```

I have already added the following permissions -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Are you running this app in 6.0?

Comment: Please show the code for `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Remove the StrictMode lines. Very bad coding.

Comment: EDIT: The code seems to work on API 19. Thanks for your help. I have a really messy code. I'll improve it now.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely to happen in cases when either you don't have the permission to write to SD card, SD card does not exist or you are not accessing the correct . 
first make sure you have a SD card .
secondly path to storage varies in different manufacturers so dont hard code it. try the following to create you directory

String pathTofile=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String fullpath=pathTofile+”your defined directory path"

above should work .

if it doesnt then try the following link

[`/storage/emulated/legacy/` vs `/storage/emulated/0/` vs `data/data/myApp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625104/storage-emulated-legacy-vs-storage-emulated-0-vs-data-data-myapp)

Comment: `you don't have the permission to write to SD card`. It looks as if OP is not writing to SD card but to external memory. And the DownloadManager makes the external path.

Comment: Also `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` delivers a path to external memory. Not to an SD card.